# How to loop through multiple upload widegets in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create multiple fileInput function to allow users to upload files. The main reason I am creating multiple upload widgets is because I want to allow users to upload through different path. What I am trying to accomplish here is to loop through all the fileInputs and save all the files into one dataframe but not able to do it in example of my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

n_attachments <- sprintf("file%s",seq(1:2))    
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('File download'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("LOAN_NUMBER", label = "Fannie Mae Loan Number", placeholder = "Please enter loan #")
      , textInput("REO_ID", label = "REO Number", placeholder = "Please enter REO #")
      , fileInput("file1", "Attachments1", accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv", ".pdf", ".doc", ".xlsx"), multiple = TRUE)
      , fileInput("file2", "Attachments2", accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv", ".pdf", ".doc", ".xlsx"), multiple = TRUE)
      , textOutput('text')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"), tags$hr()
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  bin_data <- reactive({

    attachement_data <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = character(), FILENAME = character(), LOAN_NUMBER = character(), REO_ID = character())

    for(x in n_attachments)
    {
      output$text <- renderText({ input$x })
      req(input$x)
      #     binary_data <- paste(readBin(input$file1$datapath, what="raw", n=1e6), collapse="-")
      #     attachment_info <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = binary_data, FILENAME = paste0(input$file1$name))
      #     attachment_info
      binary_data=list()
      filenames=list()

      for(i in 1:length(input$x[,1])){
        binary_data[[i]] <- paste(readBin(input$x[[i, 'datapath']], what = "raw", n=1e6), collapse = "-")
        filenames[[i]] <- input$x[[i, 'name']]
      }
      bin_data_frame <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = as.character(unlist(binary_data)), FILENAME = as.character(unlist(filenames)))
      bin_data_frame$LOAN_NUMBER <- input$LOAN_NUMBER
      bin_data_frame$REO_ID <- input$REO_ID
      attachement_data <- rbind(attachement_data, bin_data_frame)
    }
    save(attachement_data, file="attachement_data.RData")
    attachement_data
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    bin_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: forgot the beginning the code I have n_attachments <- sprintf("file%s",seq(1:2))

Comment: Please edit and update your post with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I figured it out, I have to use input[[x]] instead of input$x, and I added couple lines to check how many fileinputs are uploaded.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  bin_data <- reactive({

    attachement_data <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = character(), FILENAME = character(), LOAN_NUMBER = character(), REO_ID = character())

    k <- 0
    for(x in n_attachments)
    {
      if(!is.null(input[[x]]))
      {
        k = k + 1
      }
    }

    for(x in n_attachments[0:k])
    {
      if(!is.null(input[[x]]))
      {
      output$text <- renderText({ input[[x]] })
      req(input[[x]])
      #     binary_data <- paste(readBin(input$file1$datapath, what="raw", n=1e6), collapse="-")
      #     attachment_info <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = binary_data, FILENAME = paste0(input$file1$name))
      #     attachment_info
      binary_data=list()
      filenames=list()

      for(i in 1:length(input[[x]][,1])){
        binary_data[[i]] <- paste(readBin(input[[x]][[i, 'datapath']], what = "raw", n=1e6), collapse = "-")
        filenames[[i]] <- input[[x]][[i, 'name']]
      }
      bin_data_frame <- data.frame(ATTACHMENT = as.character(unlist(binary_data)), FILENAME = as.character(unlist(filenames)))
      bin_data_frame$LOAN_NUMBER <- input$LOAN_NUMBER
      bin_data_frame$REO_ID <- input$REO_ID
      attachement_data <- rbind(attachement_data, bin_data_frame)
      }
    }
    save(attachement_data, file="attachement_data.RData")
    attachement_data
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    bin_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```